# Saving data from a tableview cell on UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get and save data from a cell on event of UILongPressGestureRecognizer. What I am trying is that when user taps and hold for long then a dialogue box will be opened (which will have 3 or more buttons) from there user will have the choice to save the specific cell data, or to delete that cell from table or to go to another screen.

Below is the code I am using for this purpose:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
    pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
    [pressRecongnizer release];
}

if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]){
    cell.textLabel.text = 
    [self.filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else{
    cell.textLabel.text =
    [self.groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;}

- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add to Favourites", @"Take to Map", @"Delete" ,nil] ;
[alert show];}
```

Here I want to know how can I save the data to my coreData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIGestureRecognizer has a view property which represents the view it is attached to.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[recognizer view];
NSString *text = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Since you put a gesture recognizer on each cell, you can easily use the above code to grab a specific cell.

Note that you'll have to implement UIAlertDelegate methods and save your data somewhere temporarily as whatever choice the user picks will be reflected in a separate method.

Edit:

Since the user's choice in a UIAlertView is given in a different method, you will have to save a reference to the cell (whether you create an instance variable of the indexPath, the cell, etc...it's up to you).

```
- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[recognizer view];

     self.myText = cell.textLabel.text;
     self.currentCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add to Favourites", @"Take to Map", @"Delete" ,nil] ;
     [alert show];
 }
```

To delete a cell, you first need to delete it from your data source. By now, you are in your delegate method:

```
if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Delete"]) {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.currentCellIndexPath]; // in this example, I saved the reference to the cell using a property

    // last line of example code
}
```

Now you need to update your table view in one of two ways. You can either instantly refresh the table view by calling:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Or, if you want the nice delete animation table views have, you can use:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.currentCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: but one part of my question is left which is that how can I delete the specific cell from table, if user taps the delete button from dialog

Comment: Oh, sorry! Didn't notice. Edited =).